# Style column with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to style an entire column in a table. The column should correspond to the element with **`id="current"`** in the **`thead`** row.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><div id="current"></div></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now, I can add a class to the correct column, I just need to figure out a way to tell the column count number.

```
var num = ???
$('td:nth-child(num)').addClass('selectedCol');
```

Comment: you want to use a variable.. not a string so you need to do `$('td:nth-child(' + num + ')')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
$("#current").closest('td').index()
```